# Calculating bezout coefficients in haskell

Tags: haskell

So I've been trying to calculate Bezout coefficients. All the solutions I've seen do this with calculating GCD at the same time. I already have a method for this.

So this are differents parts of the code I've tried.

```
computeCoeffs :: Int -> Int -> (Int, Int)
computeCoeffs :: Int -> Int -> (Int, Int)
computeCoeffs a b =
  let bq = a - r; (q, r) = a `quotRem` b 
           in if b == 0 
              then (1, 0)
              else ((v, (u - q * v)) = computeCoeffs (a, b))
                    where a * v + b * (u - q * v) = gcd (a, b)
```

or instead of the last lines

```
 let (q, r) = a `quotRem` b
 let r = a - bq
 | b == 0 = (1, 0)
 | otherwise (v, (u-qv)) = computeCoeffs (a, b)
     where a * v + b(u - q * v) = gcd (a, b)
```

I've tried switching lets places, removing or adding guards, but it still keeps throwing errors.

Comment: Can you please give a hint at things that are wrong?

Comment: how do you expect this to be resolved `(u-qv)` in assignment `(v, (u-qv)) = computeCoeffs (a, b)`

Comment: What's wrong is this attempt demonstrates an understanding that could be greatly improved with some study.

Comment: Well, I need to know what to study, and where to start, right? As you can guess, the answer "study Haskell" is too general.

Comment: I gave you the name of a specific text. Study the basics of the language.

Answer (score 1):

something like this should work, need to handle edge cases for "division by zero" error

```
computeCoeff a b = go a b 1 0 0 1
     where go a b s0 s1 t0 t1 | r==0 = (s1,t1)
                              | otherwise = go b r s1 s t1 t
                              where (q,r) = quotRem a b
                                    (s,t) = (s0-s1*q, t0-t1*q)

> computeCoeff 240 46
(-9,47)
```

reference: [Extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm)